# Morphing images into each other using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a directory containing jpegs. Using `ffmpeg` I want to read the images and create a video out of it. The images should morph into each other, every image should be visible ~2 seconds.

So far, I came up with this:

```
ffmpeg -i %d.jpg -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p  ./bla.mp4
```

Now what I'm missing is the morping part. I know there is a "morph" filter, however no matter how I try it, I either get an error that `No such filter: 'morph'` (even tho I compiled ffmpeg on own, making sure the needed libs are included) or I get a random 0xfff something error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the [xfade](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Xfade) filter, maybe? This is the command I just used

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -loop 1 -t 11 -i image1.png \
    -framerate 30 -loop 1 -t 11 -i img2.webp \
    -filter_complex "[0][1]xfade=transition=fade:duration=10:offset=1,format=yuv420p,fps=30" \
    -c:v libvpx-vp9 -b:v 0 -speed 1 -crf 25 morph1.webm
```

This produces a 12 second video of the first image for 1s, then fading it into the other image for 11 seconds.

The important part is listing the images (first two lines) with the amount of time they'll be displayed, and the filter settings (third line). It's entirely possible there's unnecessary settings here (possibly duplicating `loop 1` and including both `framerate 30` in the images and `,fps=30`) but this works for me.

Comment: Mhm. But I do have a directory with n number of images and I want to fade them into another, not fading only 1 image into another then wait for 11 seconds.